# Conditional Types for Typescript Request/Response

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm currently playing around with `typescript@next` which now has the [Conditional Types PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) merged.

What I'm attempting to do is create a method that takes a deep record for a data model type and returns a kind of deep pick based on the fields in the record. For instance, I want to be able to do the following:

```
loadUser({
    id: true,
    name: {
     first: true
    }
});
```

When the `User` type looks like

```
type User = {
    name: {
        first: string;
        last: string;
    };
    id: string;
}
```

and the return value of `loadUser` in this case would match

```
{
    id: string;
    name: {
        first: string;
    }
}
```

What I've done so far is the following:

```
type DeepSelect<T> = {[K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends string ? boolean : DeepSelect<T[K]>};

type DeepPick<T, S extends DeepSelect<T>> = {[K in keyof S]: S[K] extends DeepSelect<infer U> ? DeepPick<T[K], U> : T[K]}

function loadUser<S extends DeepSelect<User>>(select: S): DeepPick<User, S> {
    ...
}
```

The problem is two-fold:

1. Any use of `T[K]` in the `DeepPick` definition errors with `type K cannot be used to index type T`.

I feel that given the definition of `DeepSelect` in which all keys come from keys in it's generic `T`, `T[K]` is perfectly valid here because any keys in `S` are also going to be keys in `T`.

<strike>2. The last use of `S[K]` in the `DeepPick` definition errors saying that `type boolean | DeepSelect<T[K]> is not assignable to type DeepSelect<T[K]>`</strike>

And here, I feel that because this part of the type condition is only ever hit if `S[K]` does not extend boolean, then it should be able to infer that `S[K]` is not `boolean | DeepSelect<T[K]>` but is instead only `DeepSelect<T[K]>`

I realize that since this PR was only merged yesterday, not many people will have vast insight into these matters, but I would be very thankful if anyone could help me understand how I could correctly structure these types.

### Update 1

Alright, I think I've solved problem #2 using the, also new, [Type Inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496). I've changed the definition of the `DeepPick` type from:

```
type DeepPick<T, S extends DeepSelect<T>> = {[K in keyof S]: S[K] extends boolean ? T[K] : DeepPick<T[K], S[K]>}
```

to:

```
type DeepPick<T, S extends DeepSelect<T>> = {[K in keyof S]: S[K] extends DeepSelect<infer U> ? DeepPick<T[K], U> : T[K]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed bleeding-edge stuff, so I don't know if the advice I'm giving will even be *relevant* by the next release, let alone *good*.  That said, I've got something like this:

```
type DeepSelect<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]? : T[K] extends object ? DeepSelect<T[K]> : true
};

type DeepPick<T, S> = {
  [K in keyof S & keyof T]: S[K] extends true ? T[K] : DeepPick<T[K], S[K]>
}
```

I've changed both of them to handle only `true` instead of `boolean`, since it seems that you don't really intend `false` to signal that the property should be included (do you?).

I've also changed `DeepSelect` to recurse down if the property is an `object`, so it should continue to work if `User` has some non-`string` properties (e.g., `age: number`?).  This makes it a bit more general.

Finally, I've removed the constraint on `DeepPick` that `S` needs to extend `DeepSelect<T>`, and instead of mapping over `keyof S` I'm mapping over `keyof S & keyof T`.  Removing the constraint guarantees that the recursion will work, and the intersection over the keys of `S` and `T` guarantees that the compiler will recognize that both `T[K]` and `S[K]` exist.  It's possible that the compiler might in a perfect world realize that the way you wrote it is valid, but I guess the world isn't perfect.

Note that the function `loadUser` still has the constraint on `S`:

```
declare function loadUser<S extends DeepSelect<User>>(
  select: S
): DeepPick<User, S>;
```

so it will work as desired:

```
const u = loadUser({
    id: true,
    name: {
     first: true
    }
});
u.id
u.name.first
```

---

Note, in both your and my code, there don't seem to be [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) on the object passed to `loadUser()`.  For example:

```
const u = loadUser({
    ib: true, // no error, oops
    name: {
     first: true
    }
});
u.id // error 
u.name.first
```

I don't know why that is, or if it's a bug, or a limitation, or what.  But you should keep it in mind, maybe.  Or maybe not, if the feature changes before release.    Who knows!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I do like the change from `boolean` to `true`, however I did notice that if you type it as `true` then you can't build up a `select` object before passing it to `loadUser` as it interprets the `true`s in the object as being of type `boolean` instead of `true`, so I might stick with `boolean` for now. But this all works just great. Thanks again.